# Scipy CSR matrix: subtract only from non-zero values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large matrix that I want to perform calculations on.
To make things easier to understand, here are examples of what I want to do using smaller data:
I use a sparse CSR matrix like this (shape of the actual matrix is `(9000, 900)`):

```
x = sp.csr_matrix(np.array([[1,0,2],[1,1,0]]))

# > (0, 0)  1
#   (0, 2)  2
#   (1, 0)  1
#   (1, 1)  1
```

I then have a vector of appropriate shape that I want to subtract from the matrix (shape of the actual vector is `(,9000)` ):

```
y = np.array([1, 1])
res = x - np.array([y]).T

# > matrix([[ 0, -1,  1],
#           [ 0,  0, -1]])
```

This also subtracts from values that are zero in the sparse matrix, but I want to only subtract form non-zero values. I tried using scipys `.nonzero()`, like this:

```
x[x.nonzero()] - np.array([y]).T
```

which works on this small example, but when I try it on my actual data more than 32 GB of RAM are being used. Performing the calculation without `.nonzero()` works perfectly fine and barely takes a second.

What is an efficient way of performing the subtraction only on non-zero values?

**EDIT:**
I realized that my question is a bit unclear, and I have also found the solution, so here is a clarification of the question and then an answer:

I have a matrix with 9000 rows and a column-vector with 9000 rows. I wanted to subtract the value in a row of the column vector from all non-zero values of the corresponding matrix row. So for my example matrix `sp.csr_matrix(np.array([[1,0,2],[1,1,0]]))` and vector `np.array([1, 1])`, the result should be

```
[[0 0 1]
 [0 0 0]]
```

I thought that my attempt at using `.nonzero()` calcualted just that, but I was wrong. However, I found the correct way of doing it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045524/subtracting-a-vector-from-non-zero-values-of-a-sparse-matrix). So this is the working code, which also does not cause any RAM issues :

```
x = sp.csr_matrix(np.array([[1,0,2],[1,1,0]]))
y = np.array([1,1])
nz = x.nonzero()
x[nz] -= y[nz[0]]
```

Comment: The shape does not match: 9900 vs 9000. Is this a mistake? Additionally, subtracting columns and non-zero values are two very different operation. Which one do you want? Please clarify this point.

Comment: `x.data` is the array of nonzero values.

Comment: @JérômeRichard yes I made a typo regarding the dimensions. I also found another post which pretty much answers the question, so this should maybe be flagged as duplicate